# Getting Checked Items in a ListView in Virtual Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, virtualmode

How can I iterate through all **Checked Items** in a **ListView** control that is operating in **Virtual Mode**?

I am using the *CacheVirtualItems* and *RetrieveVirtualItem* event handlers and implemented a basic cache handling.

Documentation says in Virtual Mode CheckedItems and SelectedItems would throw an exception as the Items collection is not being used. For what I have been reading one should rely on **CheckedIndices** and **SelectedIndices** in Virtual Mode but it appears that statement is incorrect because an attempt to use them in Virtual Mode yields an *Invalid Operation Exception*.

So, how do I go about the checked items? each ListViewItem in my control has a checkbox that may or may not be checked.

Comment: Has anyone found a workaround for this issue? Trying to avoid using a third party library. If I can iterate through my checked items/indices then I will be all set!